# Using Dynamic Table name in ADO.NET Source Editor

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS data flow task where I am trying to load data from a source table using ***ADO.NET Source Editor*** into a SQL Server table.

#### The problem:

The source table name is dynamic and depends on the current date.

> Example: If I want to load today's data then the table name would be `Sample_03292017_data` and if loading tomorrow's data then it would be `Sample_03302017_Data`.

I did some research and found how to pass parameters to an ***ADO.NET Source Editor*** to use in *`where` conditions* but I couldn't find anything on how to use this parameter in a table name.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? My query is really simple:

```
select * from Sample_[DateParameter]_Data.
```

I am using Visual Studio Data Tools 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression must be set on the `Data Flow Task` not in the `Ado.net Source`

Follow this steps to set an expression for an `Ado.net Source`:

1. in the `control flow` tab click on the `Data Flow Task` and press `F4` to show the properties tab
2. Click on the expression button, it show up a form like shown below

[image]

3. choose `[Ado.net Source].sqlcommand` property  and click on the expression builder button

[image]

4. write the following expression `"select * from Sample_ " + @[User::DateParameter] + "_Data"` *(assuming that your data parameter is stored in a variable named `DateParameter`)*

[image]

Comment: Yes, I followed all those steps and right now the query is coming up correctly in the source editor but it shows no columns and when I try to preview the data it gives me the below error;

There was an error displaying the preview.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

ERROR [37000] [Rocket U2][U2ODBC][1401257]Error ID: 21  Severity: ERROR  Facility: DBCAPERR - SQL Syntax error. (U2ODBC.DLL)

Comment: Check your sql command syntax, test it on mysql workbench before using it.

Comment: @Bhoomika if this answer solved your issue you have to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) else give me a feedback

Answer (score 2):

You should use dynamic SQL to achieve this. If you are using `ADO.net` as `Connection Type`, copy and paste the following to your SQL statement:

```
Declare @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = 'Select * from ' + @TABLE
EXEC(@SQL)
```

In the parameter page, you need to `Add` new parameter which has `@TABLE` as the `parameter name` and leave the size as `-1`. The `@Table` variable should be decided by the `expression` from variable setting page.